# Confused about this conjugation of 忘れる

Tags: grammar, conjugations, て-form, song-lyrics, song

In KICK BACK, there is a line of the song that goes なんか忘れちゃってんだ. I'm confused specifically about the 忘れちゃってんだ. I haven't really seen this sort of conjugation before. I'm thinking it's possibly 忘れる + ちゃ + んだ, the latter two being connected by て. If that's the case, it seems to express realization on top of must (ちゃ), as in "must have forgotten...". Could be entirely wrong, I don't even know if the ちゃ in ちゃいけない can be used alone/in a positive manner. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 忘れてしまう contracts to 忘れちゃう, you can probably figure it out from there

Comment: Related: [Why progressive tense (～ている) is not used in this case?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52819/43676)

Comment: @Angelos - [Comments are not for answers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/78).