# what does してん do here?

Tags: particles

「なにしてんだよ。」
appears in this book ISBN-13: 978-0143118336
On page 61, the longer context is

> 下の子どもの泣き声が聞こえた。いつの間にか、姿が見えなくなっている。あわてて辺りを見渡した私に、上の娘が、あの子、あんなところにいる、と笑いながら教えてくれた。はじめの仔猫のいた場所に、下の子どもはうずくまって泣いていた。仔猫を見つけて、勢いこんで茂みに飛び込んだのはよいが、仔猫はさっさとどこかに行ってしまい、残された子どもは茂みの外にどうやって出たらよいのか分からなくなって、泣きだしたのだった。
>   **なにしてんだよ**。お前につかまえられるわけないのに。
>   娘はしゃがみ込んで茂みのなかにいる弟に呼びかける。
>   ばかみたい。早く出ておいでよ。

I assume that 
「なに」 is 「何」
「だ」 means the past
「よ」 and asks for agreement
but how does the 「してん」 work?

I tried looking up the grammar in three places, but I can't figure it out.

- https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?9T
- https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%82%88
- https://www.imabi.net/theparticleshite.htm

I'm sure the answer is really easy; I just don't know it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contraction of ～てるのか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30055/contraction-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b)

Comment: ^ Just to be clear, I'm not saying it is a contraction of てるのか, but see the answer in that post.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I found these answers very helpful:

Answer (score 0):

なにしてんだよ is an informal contraction of 何をしているんだよ。

*(By the way, you said "だ means the past" but that is incorrect. だ is the non-past copula).*